# Adjacent <div>s with a transform scaled container causes inset box-shadow to fail

Tags: html, css, transform

EDIT: Chromium-specific issue it seems...

I'm using a div element that contains other div elements, like a column with cells in a table. Columns are next to each other with proper absolute positioning. When I use box-shadow inset to emulate borders, things look great, until the outermost container gets a transform scale on it, then the box-shadow border leaks into vertical borders when I only want horizontal borders. Any ideas?

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/mattalie/pen/RwazNmj

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='group'>
    <div class='col' style='left:5px;width:125px'>
      <div class='cell'>2000</div>
      <div class='cell'>2000</div>
      <div class='cell'>2000</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col' style='left:130px;width:125px'>
      <div class='cell'>asdfasdf</div>
      <div class='cell'>asdfasdf</div>
      <div class='cell'>asdfasdf</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col' style='left:255px;width:125px'>
      <div class='cell'>999999</div>
      <div class='cell'>999999</div>
      <div class='cell'>999999</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  transform: scale(0.672);
}

.group {
  font-size: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thanks in advance, this one is killing me.

[Pic - vertical lines should not be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv4Vv.png)

Comment: First off: Don't use `//` for comments in CSS. It's not allowed and can lead to other errors. Also reconsider absolute positioning. It's not "flexible" and can easily break. For this case grid layout seems more sensible. To your problem: Is this in all browsers? Can you post an image showing the problem?

Comment: Not all browsers, but Chrome and "new" Edge so seems Chromium specific (haven't tested Safari). Firefox is good. Updated post above with image link.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to have to do with `box-shadow`. Chrome seems to have problems with rounding when using `transform` and which creates gaps between elements so that the background shines through.

Here are two other posts that have similar problems:

[Transform Scale Causing Gaps/Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504186/transform-scale-causing-gaps-lines)

[Scaling results in gaps between CSS shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818772/scaling-results-in-gaps-between-css-shapes/21819630)

However there doesn't seem to be a universal solution. Based on those posts and some experiments my first suggestion would be to take a step back and to look for a different solution to your design.

What you are currently doing seems to be a bit hacky to me (absolute positioning, using `box-shadow` to emulate borders) anyway, so you may want to re-consider these choices and also check if you need to use `transform` or if you need to have different background colors and and a box-shadow here which shine through the gaps.

Alternatively one even more hacky solution would ironically use normal (outer) `box-shadow`s to fill in the gaps, in your case a white shadow on the columns and cells:

```
.col {
  /* ... */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white;
}

.cell {
  /* ... */
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px #000000, 0 0 0 1px white;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't just the background shining through (which my codepen has as yellow), there is also black box-shadow leaking around the sides even though I specify 0px for R/L. Also unfortunate, I am stuck with the legacy code that is using absolute positioned divs for columns and cells, and box-shadow for borders due to how they overlap with square intersections... border CSS will miter and look terrible.
So far my two best choices are also hacks, either margin -1px on the cell or setting the blur radius to something like 0.00001px also helps (no idea why), but doesn't fully mitigate.